# what would this ratio be equal to in a trapezium?

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]
What would be the logical reason for the answer and could you mention the theorems used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is (2).

Draw a line, $L$, through $O$ parallel to the trapezoid's bases. Denote by $A$ $L$'s intersection with $\overline{PS}$, and denote by $B$ $L$'s intersection with $\overline{QR}$. Since a parallel to one of the sides of a triangle divides the other two sides proportionally,

$$
\frac{PO}{OR}\overset{\Delta PQR}{=} \frac{QB}{BR} \overset{\Delta SQR}{=} \frac{QO}{OS}.
$$

Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{PO - OR}{OR} &= \frac{QO - OS}{OS}, \\
\frac{PO + OR}{OR} &= \frac{QO + OS}{OS}.
\end{align}
$$

Therefore

$$
\frac{PO-OR}{QO-OS} = \frac{OR}{OS} = \frac{PO+OR}{QO+OS} =\frac{PR}{QS}.
$$

Comment: Could you elucidate the last step,  i couldn't understand why PO-OR/QO-OS=OR/OS

Comment: how could PO-OR/QO-OS = OR/OS ? I couldn't understand this

Comment: @AnamikaGhosh: It results from the equation $$\frac{PO-OR}{OR} =\frac{QO-OS}{OS}$$ by multiplying both sides by $$\frac{OR}{QO-OS}$$.